# Как найти косое (псевдоскалярное) произведение векторов?

Tags: математика, вычислительная-геометрия

У меня сразу два вопроса по вычислительной геометрии. Мне необходимо найти косое (псевдоскалярное) произведение векторов, каждый из которых задан двумя точками.

Нашел только такую инфу:

> если векторы заданы координатами a(x1, y1), b(x2, y2) то косое
> произведение [a, b] = x1y2 — x2y1.

Вопрос 1: Каким образом каждый вектор задается одной точкой? Я правильно понял, что при такой записи предполагается, что начало вектора совпадает с началом координат, а указанные координаты вектора - это координаты конца вектора?

Вопрос 2: Если в моем случае каждый вектор задан двумя точками, то мне надо перед вычислением их косого произведение преобразовать каждый из векторов так, чтобы их начала совпадали с началом координат?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Да, верно.
2. Чтоб производить операции с векторами их надо приложить к одной точке - начало координат подойдет потому как площадь под векторами не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

"Координатами вектора являются координаты конечной точки этого вектора, если вектор расположен так, что его начало находится в начале координат. Если вектор находится на координатной плоскости, то каждая координата вектора равна разности соответствующих координат его конца и начала."

В вашем случае :каждая координата вектора равна разности соответствующих координат его конца и начала